# Why the port number can not be specified when sending a request to a server?

Tags: protocol-theory

Using any protocol to transfer files on web.For example when a client is sending a request to www.google.com, the requested page will be given to the client, in this case he/she did not use a port numbr wen writing. So my question is that why we do not specify a port number when sending request?

Comment: What do you mean by "the client"? If you mean a webbrowser, that *does* connect to a port number: a known port for HTTP or HTTPS (80/443). If you mean something else, you really need to be more on what you're asking.

Comment: Ok. In web development, can u suggest why the port can not be specifiied when sendind a request to the web browser?

Comment: You're still not making much sense here. Who sends what request *to* a webbrowser?

Comment: FYI related: http://serverfault.com/questions/313439/where-is-the-documentation-that-states-tcp-and-udp-source-port-should-be-over-10

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5):

Actually the port can be specified.

However, there are some standard ports
80 => HTTP
443 => HTTPS

When you don't enter anything into your browser (eg. http://www.google.com) your browser is really requesting (http://www.google.com:80) - the port number is just implied. Likewise, when you view https://www.google.com your browser is really making a request to https://www.google.com:443

Comment: Exactly.  You can specify port in connection.  You can for example telnet to port 25 (SMTP).